# Object cannot be converted

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So im trying to convert a number in from a array that has both strings and integers, but keep getting that error. If i try to parse it, i get the error that it cannot be converted to string, if i try to use the array variable straight, i get that it cannot be converted to int..
heres the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.*;

public class sav
{
public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException{
   try{
int rows = 0;
//String temp;
int tempint = 0;
Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("sav_duom.txt"));
while (file.hasNextLine())
{
    rows++;
    file.nextLine();
}

file = new Scanner (new File("sav_duom.txt"));
System.out.println(rows);
Object[][] data = new Object[rows][5];
for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++)
{
    String str = file.nextLine();
    String[] tokens= str.split(",");
        int temp = data[i][4];
        //temp = temp.replaceAll("\\W","");
        //tempint = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    for (int j = 0;j<5;j++)
    {

        if(temp > 5)
        {
        data[i][j] = tokens[j]; 
        System.out.print(data[i][j]);
        if(j == 3){
        System.out.print(":");
        } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
        }
    }     
    System.out.print(" \n");
}
file.close();
        }
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i get the error that it cannot be converted to string

You need to convert to store values in different types.

From `String` to `int` use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

From `int` to `String` use [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))

```
String s = String.valueOf(1234);
```

---

Also, depending of the type of data in your files declare `data` array as `int[][]` or `String[][]`

Comment: Well, i converted to string first, and then to int, but now im getting this error
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at sav.main(sav.java:34)

Comment: `For input string: "null"` means there is an empty string in the file... check your data and also read the linked API methods in the update

Comment: When i try to print out the array element, that im trying to convert, it prints the strings fine